# openlayers 3 ol.source.ImageWMS.getGetFeatureInfoUrl returns bad XY

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have a singleTile layer created using `ol.source.ImageWms` and `ol.layer.Image`. Now I am trying to `getFeatureInfo` on this layer and no matter where I click on the map, the coordinates are `X=50, Y=50`

I looked into code of getFeatureInfoUrl:

```js
var extent = ol.extent.getForViewAndSize(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 0,
                ol.source.ImageWMS.GETFEATUREINFO_IMAGE_SIZE_);

var x = Math.floor((evt.coordinate[0] - extent[0]) / viewResolution);
var y = Math.floor((extent[3] - evt.coordinate[1]) / viewResolution);
```

and for my parameters it does always calculate x,y as 50, 50 for default `GETFEATUREINFO_IMAGE_SIZE_=[101,101]`. With the same parameters `ol.source.TileWms.getGetFeatureInfoUrl` returns correct coodinates but the calculations there are different.

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: we need to see the rest of the URL to see what might be happening, it might be creating a small map centred on your click

Comment: On each click the extent also changes. Does `ol.extent.getForViewAndSize` where I pass coordinate calculate extent with coordinate centered? If so it will always return 50,50.

Comment: quite possibly it does

Comment: Oh. I think I misunderstood how getFeatureInfo works. The X=50 and Y=50 are probably ok when also passing BBOX in the request. Geoserver then calculates X,Y differently each time.

Comment: that's OpenLayers calculating the X&Y - it is the pixel you clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

With `ol.source.ImageWms` the `X,Y` coordinates in `getFeatureInfoUrl` will always be 50, 50 as the clicked coordinate will be centered on default tileSize of [101,101]. Geoserver will handle the X,Y correctly as BBOX is also passed along in getFeatureInfo request.

With `ol.source.TileWms` situation is different as the `X,Y` will be calculated based on the layer `tileSize` and relative to clicked tile.

The problem in my case was that I was sending `getFeatureInfo` request with multiple `QUERY_LAYERS` which have different tileSize, filters and are of different type `(TileWms, ImageWms)` in my map, they were separated only by url. To make it work i had to separate these layers into groups based on url, tileSize, type and if it contained `CQL_FILTER` or not and then send individual getFeatureInfo request for each group.